# Pixel manipulation in OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, image-processing, opencv, augmented-reality

Lets say I have this image and in it is an object (a cube). That object is being tracked (with labels) and I manage to render a virtual cube onto it (augmented reality). Now that I can render a virtual cube onto it I want to be able to make the object 'disappear' with some really basic diminished-reality technique called "inpainting". The inpaint in question is pretty simple (it has to be or the FPS will suffer) and it requires me to do some operations on pixels and their neighbors (like with Gaussian blur or other basic image processing).

To do that I first need:

1. A mask: black background with a white cube in it.
2. Access each pixel of the initial image (at coordinates x and y) as well as its neighborhood and do stuff based on the pixel value of the mask at the same x and y coordinates. So basically the mask serves as a way to say ignore this pixel or use this pixel.

How do I do this using OpenGL? I want to be able to access pixel values 1 by 1 preferably in 2D because of the neighbors.

Do I use FBOs or PBOs? I've read many things about buffers and methods like `glDrawPixels()` but I'm having trouble putting them all together. The paper I saw this method in used the `GL_BACK` buffer but mine is already used. Some sample code (C++) would be really appreciated with all the formalities (OpenG` calls) since I'm still a beginner in OpenGL.

I'm even thinking of using OpenCV if pixel manipulation is too hard in OpenGL since my AR library (Aruco) works on top of OpenCV. In that case I will still need to get the mask (white cube on black background), convert it to a `cv::Mat` and then do my processing.

I know this approach is inefficient (going back and forth from the GPU/CPU) but my goal (for now) is to at least make the basics work.

Answer (score 2):

Setup a framebuffer object to render your original image + virtual cube. Here's a [tutorial](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_fbo.html).

Next you can attach that framebuffer texture as a input (sampler) texture of your next stage and render a quad (two triangles) that cover your mask.

In the fragment shader you should be able to sample your "screen coordinate" by reading the variable gl_FragCoord. Setting up the texture filter functions as GL_NEAREST, you can access the exact texture coordinates. Also the neighboring pixels are available with a displacement (deltaX = 2/Width, deltaY=2/Height).

Using a previous framebuffer texture as source is mandatory, as the currently active framebuffer is write only.

Comment: Thanks. I will try making it work this way and report back either once I'm done or if I lose my battle agents time.

Comment: Actually, my original "frame" (from the camera or video) is stored in a `cv::Mat` so I can make a FBO, put the image inside, make another FBO put the black background and render virtual cube in white. Use the mask FBO as a mask to modify the first FBO (inpaint) and copy it to the main buffer in the end.